# Deserializing mRSS / RSS2.0 using MonoTouch

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin.ios, mediarss

I am using mono 2.10.5 to parse an RSS 2.0 / mRSS Feed, however, i can't find .net framework [syndication namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) under System.ServiceModel nor System.ServiceModel.Web

Are these features available in Mono ? If not anyone knows a good Rss/mRSS feed deserialization library ?

Regards,

EDIT:

I just discovered the packages i am using are different as I am using the monotouch framework. When i go to Add references, the assembly version of system.servicemodel.web is 2.0.5 and the package name is mono-iphone. Is it possible to change  this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MonoTouch's version of System.ServiceModel[.Web].dll assemblies provide the same API as Silverlight. As such they can be missing some types, like [Rss20FeedFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.rss20feedformatter.aspx).

The Rss20FeedFormatter is available in Silverlight but it located inside the System.ServiceModel.Syndication.dll, which is an SDK assembly (not part of the platform code Silverlight ships with).

You can try to:

a) download the SL3/4 SDK assemblies and use them with MonoTouch. That worked well enough for Moonlight (the open source implementation of Silverlight from which MonoTouch shares a lot of it's BCL code).

b) use the source code from Mono and create your own assembly that provides Rss20FeedFormatter. Since it us **MIT.X11** licensed it's easy (legally) to reuse inside your own applications.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback ! i ended up using b) !

Comment: Glad you got it working :-) Please take the time to mark the question as answered (the green mark under the answer score) so it can help others when searching for a similar question/answer.